# android wait for filtering finish with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the next code:

```
 private fun filterCarouselItems(loggedInFilter: Boolean) {

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        if (loggedInFilter)
            filteredCarouselItems = carouselItems.filter {
                it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.LOGGEDIN.visibility
                        || it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.BOTH.visibility
            } as ArrayList<CarouselItem>
        else {
            filteredCarouselItems = carouselItems.filter {
                it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.LOGGEDOUT.visibility
                        || it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.BOTH.visibility
            } as ArrayList<CarouselItem>
        }

        withContext(Dispachers.Main) {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    }
}
```

I would like my code to execute sequentially. By this, I mean that I would like that my function finishes the filtering and after that calls the notifyDataSetChanged method. What is the best way to do this by using coroutines (without blocking UI/main thread?

Comment: use `withContext()` then `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside a coroutine.

Comment: You mean to put withContext inside launch. Tried and that gives the same result (doesn't wait for filtering finish)

Comment: I meant like this `yourScope.launch { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {...} notifyDataSetChanged()` }.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did

Comment: You can use `CompletableDeferred` to perform work off the main thread and then await on that inside coroutine scope.

Comment: In the code you're showing, the steps are synchronous and sequential. I'm guessing that in the code that calls this function you are expecting immediate results, but it won't get them because you are launching a coroutine from inside this function here. The steps inside a coroutine are sequential, but the launching of the coroutine itself is asynchronous.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So this code should work as I expect, right? This means probably that my notifyDataSetChanged() function doesn't update recyclerView data when filtering is done. Don't understand why this happens, it works when I go from one screen to another. But if I stay on the screen with recyclerview when I call notifyDataSetChanged(), it doesn't get updated...

Comment: Yes, I would expect it to work fine. Maybe you can share your complete Adapter code.

Comment: Huuuh that class is huge. And it belongs to the company that I work for so it's a little bit private :/
As I said when I am not on the home fragment, I call notifyDataSetChanged and go back to that fragment it works fine. But when I call notifyDataSetChanged  when I am on homeFragment, it doesn't update recycler. My flow is identical, I did the debugging. I will investigate it now. If anything comes to your mind from this hint write and I can try...

Comment: Seems like it might have something to do with how you're handling the `carouselItems` property from elsewhere. Maybe a `notifyDataSetChanged` call from somewhere else is interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` from background thread has no effect.

```
private fun filterCarouselItems(loggedInFilter: Boolean) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        if (loggedInFilter)
            filteredCarouselItems = carouselItems.filter {
                it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.LOGGEDIN.visibility
                        || it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.BOTH.visibility
            } as ArrayList<CarouselItem>
        else {
            filteredCarouselItems = carouselItems.filter {
                it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.LOGGEDOUT.visibility
                        || it.visible == CarouselVisibilityEnum.BOTH.visibility
            } as ArrayList<CarouselItem>
        }
        // add this line 
        withContext(Dispachers.Main) {
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I added it but still no effect. Interesting is the fact that I tried putting withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                filteredCarouselItems.clear()
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }    code in withContext. In this case, my adapter data gets updated and removes all the data from recyclerView. But when I do the filtering and try to notifyAdapter after that, it doesn't. Don't know why is this happening

Comment: So you are clearing then filtering then notify changes? What about adding the filtered list?